# syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am not getting what I am getting wrong :

```
class Acad< ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name,:email,:city,:state,:address1,:zip,:password,:password_confirmation has_secure_password
  has_many :sporcads
  has_many :sports, :through => :sporcads  
end
```

I am getting following error :

> syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

Comment: Look closer at `:password_confirmation has_secure_password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on mu's comment, the `attr_accessible` list is balking on the flag for `:password_confirmation`. `has_secure_password` is its own validation on the model and should be on its own line ([here is an example](http://www.farbeyondprogramming.com/2011/05/rails-user-authentication-using-has_secure_password/)).

So this is what it might look like:

```
class Acad< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :name,:email,:city,:state,:address1,:zip,:password, :password_confirmation
  has_many :sporcads
  has_many :sports, :through => :sporcads  
end
```